# Self - adjoint contraction operators on Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, contraction-operator, self-adjoint-operators

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be a complex Hilbert space.

Let $T:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ be a self - adjoint contraction operator.

why is the following statement true ?
$$0 \le T^2 \le I$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $( \cdot, \cdot)$ denote the inner product on $H$.

1. $(T^2x,x)=(Tx,Tx) = ||Tx||^2 \ge 0 $ for all $x \in H.$ This shows that $T^2 \ge 0.$
2. Since $T$ is a contraction, we have $||Tx|| \le ||x||$ for all $x \in H.$  Hence

$(T^2x,x)=(Tx,Tx) = ||Tx||^2  \le ||x||^2 =(x,x) $ for all $x \in H.$ This gives $T^2 \le I.$

Answer (score 1):

$\langle T^{2}x , x \rangle =\langle Tx , Tx \rangle =\|Tx\|^{2}$ so $0 \leq \langle T^{2}x , x \rangle \leq \|x\|^{2}$. This says $0 \leq T^{2} \leq I$.